# Create formula to combine different cells from multiple sheets by defining specific criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have tried Google all the different combinations I can think of, but I am not experienced enough in Excel to know how to word this properly.

My issue is I have 25 sheets (one per employee) recording the billed amounts for up to 73 different projects (listed as my rows), with one column for each month of the year. Then I have a master sheet for the year where I want to write a formula that will record the overall value of each project, per month. Since the projects are not all listed in the same row for each sheet. Currently, the last person to handle this worksheet had input each specific cell by hand so my formula looks similar to this:

`='Employee1'!c2+'Employee2'!c14+...` etc. (January)

`='Employee1'!d4+'Employee2'!d10+...` etc. (February)

This is very time-consuming and as more projects are added, and certain employees only work on certain projects, what have you, I don't have time to search each sheet and find which cell/row where each particular project is listed. I also need to do this and also filter for the month I want to consolidate?

Is there a way to search out one project by name, and then separate it by months?

Any suggestions would be a huge help and very appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably pull all the sheets into Excel's "power query" (now called "transform and get") and do all kinds of fancy analyses, but I'm old skool:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100, "projectname", Sheet1!B$2:B$100)
```

will look in sheet1 for all rows which has "projectname" in column A (up to row 100) and sum the corresponding value in column B. You can of course change A, B and 100 according to your layout. Note the placement of the dollar signs, which locks the project column into an absolute reference, but the monthly billed amounts column is a relative reference, i.e. if you copy and paste it one cell to the right, it will auto update to column C / the next month.

Unfortunately you still have to construct the full formula summing together over all 25 sheets:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100, "projectname", Sheet1!B$2:B$100) + SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100, "projectname", Sheet2!B$2:B$100) + ... + SUMIF(Sheet25!$A$2:$A$100, "projectname", Sheet25!B$2:B$100)
```

At least you can replace "projectname" with the cell reference of the project name column in your mastersheet, so not only can you copy across for different months, but also copy down for different projects.

Comment: You may also find this interesting https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4922-excel-3d-reference-sumif.html which presents a single formula to SUMIF across multiple sheets

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try this, I really appreciate your answer!